# Wordpress Post Notification with full HTML via Slack

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slack, slack-api

When I create a post in Wordpress a slack notification plugin sends notifications to a channel using the slack api. The notification works fine. What I'm trying to do is to the send the content of the post to the channel including the formatting and HTML. I can easily get the content to post to the channel, but I'm struggling to get the content to be formatted. This may be a Slack issue, but I'm not sure.

Here's the code.

```
`$message = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);`
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Slack uses their own message formatting api. I do not think it is possible to send a formatted html + css as a slack message. However, you can see if sending url to your post as an attachment isn't enough https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slack does currently only support markup formatting using a Slack specific [markup language](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting).

It does not support messages formatted in HTML or provide any automatic conversion of HTML to Slack markup (which btw. would not also not make much sense, since Slack's markup only has basic formatting features, not nothing advanced like tables, font sizes, etc.) Plus you can add [attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments), which give you some additional formatting options like adding images.

In addition Slack support a more sophisticated formatting with so called "[posts](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203950418-Compose-a-post)".  However, posts are not supported by the API, so no help here either.

That leaves you with three options:

- Convert the HTML of your posts to Slack markup plus attachments
- Convert the HTML of your posts to an image and then post that on
  Slack
- Convert the HTML of your posts to PDF and then post that on
  Slack

AFAIK there are plenty of existing converters for HTML to images or PDF, so I would suggest the 2nd or 3rd option.

Both image and PDFs will be displayed within the channel and Slack has it's own viewer to show details. Images are easier to handle, but PDFs gives you more options and a better rendering result. PDFs would also retain links in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

try referring to this repo it might help i guess you can just change some of the code or get something on there that might help.

[github/wp-slack-notification](https://github.com/vindecodex/wp-slack-notification)

> Edit:

If you want to notify slack with similar content of your posts then it is not possible because slack only accepts json with specific structuring and keys. Also slack does not accept markdown.

reference for structuring contents:
[Block Kit Builder](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Hello%2C%20Assistant%20to%20the%20Regional%20Manager%20Dwight!%20*Michael%20Scott*%20wants%20to%20know%20where%20you%27d%20like%20to%20take%20the%20Paper%20Company%20investors%20to%20dinner%20tonight.%5Cn%5Cn%20*Please%20select%20a%20restaurant%3A*%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22*Farmhouse%20Thai%20Cuisine*%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%201528%20reviews%5Cn%20They%20do%20have%20some%20vegan%20options%2C%20like%20the%20roti%20and%20curry%2C%20plus%20they%20have%20a%20ton%20of%20salad%20stuff%20and%20noodles%20can%20be%20ordered%20without%20meat!!%20They%20have%20something%20for%20everyone%20here%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2Fc7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22*Kin%20Khao*%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%201638%20reviews%5Cn%20The%20sticky%20rice%20also%20goes%20wonderfully%20with%20the%20caramelized%20pork%20belly%2C%20which%20is%20absolutely%20melt-in-your-mouth%20and%20so%20soft.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2Fkorel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22*Ler%20Ros*%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%202082%20reviews%5Cn%20I%20would%20really%20recommend%20the%20%20Yum%20Koh%20Moo%20Yang%20-%20Spicy%20lime%20dressing%20and%20roasted%20quick%20marinated%20pork%20shoulder%2C%20basil%20leaves%2C%20chili%20%26%20rice%20powder.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2FDawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22actions%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Farmhouse%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Kin%20Khao%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Ler%20Ros%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%5D%7D%5D)

If you try image or pdf version of content you want to notify it might be small in size.

I suggest, why not get the post contents using wordpress provided functions then pass it in a json format using `json_encode` and use Block Kit Builder if what you want contents will look like.

```php
$data_encoded = array(
    "payload" => json_encode(create_message())
  );
    $post_on_slack = wp_remote_post($webhook_endpoint, array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'headers' => array(),
      'body' => $data_encoded,
    )
  );
```

for the $webhook_endpoint you can refer to the repo on how to get it.

```php
function create_message() {
$data = array(
    // structure here depends on what your Block Kit Builder
);
return $data;
}
```

The first Block of Code I created can be wrapped into function so that you can call it via hooks something like

`add_action("save_post","you_function");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you add/explain some key details from the github repository which answer the issue of the OP?