# Is there a way to show the content of a HTML email in a slack channel

Tags: html-email, slack, slack-api, email

I'm trying to send an email report to a slack channel. The report have contents in table format.  The contents are getting displayed in the channel but not in a readable format since its not in table layout as with the original email.

I tried doing some search on this and couldn't come up with anything else other than opening mail from slack itself by following the open original link in the top right corner

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you want to do? What do you mean by "email as it is"? e.g. do you want an email link or just the email address.

Comment: "email as it is" meant the contents of email [which includes the tables, links etc].

Comment: Ah ok. In which format is that content? HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Post Notification with full HTML via Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796411/wordpress-post-notification-with-full-html-via-slack)

Comment: @Erik, Thanks for the response!!
Yes the content is in HTML and there could be links as well, so I believe conversion from HTML to images won't help.

Comment: If you need to retain format and links then your best option I think is to convert emails to PDF. Slack will show the content of PDFs in channel and also has a viewer for it.

Comment: See also this more definitive answer for what it does support natively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816333/does-slack-support-markdown-tables